# Windows Seven no boot sector

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader

The story
A friend got a virus (rootkit) on their windows seven install and I offered to try and fix it (the virus was the google redirect tdss rootkit). After many attempts I finally got rid of it with Kapserky Rescue CD 10

Then when I go to boot into windows I get a error, specifically this

> File: \Boot\BCD
>
> Status: 0xc0000000f
>
> Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.

Ok So I go to google and search try some things get the drive mounted with diskpart turns out the Boot folder is gone.

I have tried tutorials on the internet but it seems I can't get teh boot file recreated;

I run... (using cmd on the windows 7 install usb drive)

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

At this point it say I have one windows install and asks if I want to add it; I click yes and it says 
 The requested system device cannot be found

Why yes it can I am able to acess all the files on it and bootrec found it, so what gives

BTW some of the solutions say to use bcedit command which it seems the USB windows 7 install doesn't work.

Also I have tried using the system repair but it can't find any windows installs.

Please help :)

Comment: Does your friend have a backup of his data? In which case a full reinstallation is not only the quickest but also the safest option.

Comment: No he does not though I can still copy it off the drive; that is what i am planning on doing but I was hoping to not do that as a) it is a pain to reinstall b) pain to put all the data back c) pain to reinstall all the programs and d) pain to update windows again

Comment: Agreed with all of that. Still I would not trust that PC again for things like internet banking, online shopping etc. A clean install is a lot of work, but it is the safe choice. Followed by a good backup (CloneZilla, Acronis. ghost, ...) of the desktop after reinstalling, windows updates, etc,, but before a lot of quickly outdated programs get installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the installation disk and go to the command prompt. From there, run `bootrec`:

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

**References**

- [Use the Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment to troubleshoot and repair startup issues in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)

Comment: I tried that, didn't work eventually I just reinstalled after imaging.

Comment: Good to know. As an alternative, [Windows PE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.09.desktopfiles.aspx) and [VistaPE](http://www.vistape.net/) have utilities which may help for future reference.